# How to convert JSON in other form?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm just starting with JSON, and I have a beginners question.

I have JSON data in that form:

```
[{"price":"0"},{"price":"124"},{"price":"12"},{"price":"0"},{"price":"124"}]
```

Is it possible to change it, so the output will be `[0,124,12,0,124]`?

Comment: Depends on the language, but it's simply the JSON's values.

Comment: im working in javascript, how would i put just values in array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery you can use this function:

```js
function objectArrayToValueString(objectArray) {

    var output = objectArray.map(function (each) {
        return parseInt(each.price);
    });

    return JSON.stringify(output);
}

var objectArray = [{ "price": "0" }, { "price": "124" }, { "price": "12" }, { "price": "0" }, { "price": "124" }];

var result = objectArrayToValueString(objectArray);

alert(result);
```

Comment: You are going round round for simple solution , can you explain why this much code is needed @HajkHovhannisyan

Comment: Because it's "platform independent" algorithm. But yes, you're right. Much cleaner solution in javascript is yours with JSON.stringify(output);

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = [{"price":"0"},{"price":"124"},{"price":"12"},{"price":"0"},{"price":"124"}]

var arr2 = []

for (i in arr){ 
  arr2.push(arr[i].price)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use map function,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
var temp = [{"price":"0"},{"price":"124"},{"price":"12"},{"price":"0"},{"price":"124"}];


 var arr = temp .map(function (el) {
      return el.price;
    });

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = [{"price":"0"},{"price":"124"},{"price":"12"},{"price":"0"},{"price":"124"}];

var output = array.map(function(each){
  return parseInt(each.price);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pasrseInt()` function, which converts strings to integers, and `JSON.parse()`, which creates a javascript object from a json string.

So:

```
var s = '[{"price":"0"},{"price":"124"},{"price":"12"},{"price":"0"},{"price":"124"}]'
var list = JSON.parse(s)
var newArray = []
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    var element = list[i]
    var obj = {}
    for (key in element) {
        obj[key] = parseInt(element[key])
    }
    newArray.push(obj)
}
s = JSON.stringify(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Loop through your array of JSON objects a replace that JSON object with value

```
var arr =[{"price":"0"},{"price":"124"},{"price":"12"},{"price":"0"},"price":"124"}];

for (i in arr){   
  arr[i]=parseInt(arr[i].price);  
}
console.log(arr);
```